# std::remove not working correctly, still has extra elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, stl

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
auto i = std::remove(v.begin(),v.end(),3); 
for(auto j = v.begin(); j!= v.end();++j)
   std::cout << *j;
```

Actual output : `12455`

Where does extra 5 come from?

Desired output : `1245`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`remove` doesnt actually remove the elements](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove.html)

> Remove removes from the range `[first, last)` all elements that are equal to `value`. That is, remove returns an iterator `new_last` such that the range `[first, new_last)` contains no elements equal to `value`. [1](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove) The iterators in the range `[new_last, last)` are all **still dereferenceable**, but the elements that they point to are **unspecified**. Remove is stable, meaning that the relative order of elements that are not equal to value is unchanged.`

`std::remove` algorithm works only using a pair of forward iterators and in general knows nothing about the underlying container.

You need to use the [`erase-remove`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove) idiom to **actually** remove the element i.e combine `erase` with `remove`

```
auto i = std::remove(v.begin(),v.end(),3);
v.erase(i,v.end());
for(auto j = v.begin(); j!= v.end();++j)
   std::cout << *j;
```

Comment: @Rookie: Look at that `remove()` call again. That algorithm sees a sequence and has no access to the container, so how could it remove anything from it?

Comment: "the erase-remove idiom" - which is given right at the end of the page, in the "notes".

Comment: @GMan: I meant to upvote your answer and delete my above comment. Why did you delete your answer? It contains an important point Prasoon hadn't made (yet).

Comment: @Prasoon: You only need to employ the erase-remove idiom if you actually want the container to change size. If you only use the iterators afterwards, and don't mind the container assembling some junk at the end, you could just use that new end iterator and spare a few CPU cycles wasted on resizing the container.

Comment: @sbi : I think OP actually wanted to change `v` 's size. :-)

Comment: @Prasoon: He might, but your answer will also be found by those who might not need it. And even Rookie might be better off without. Given the question, it's likely he didn't even know he could that.

Comment: @Prasoon, not to nit pick, remove *does remove elements*, it removes them from the sequence, and it returns a logical end of the new sequence as a result of the removal of the items. The erase is simply to adjust the container, to "cleanup".

Comment: @sbi: I have to agree with Prasoon in this one. The question is quite clear in that he wants the container after the operation not to contain the last element (duplicate 5). I don't think that this question/answer can be misinterpreted by anyone in the future. The question is clear and precise, the answer is correct. Also, I would not like to see the elements left at the end of the container just to spare a few CPU cycles... 99.99% of the time that micro-optimization would be unneeded, and just posting it in the answer might make people believe that it is worth doing it.

Comment: @David: but the distinction is significant, and I agree with @sbi that the OP should be aware of it. Anything that nudges people towards a better understanding of the library they're using is a good thing, I'd say.

Comment: BTW, if you need to micro-optimize this for a vector (and assuming a trivial destructor in the contained type), it is much more sensible to recommend doing a `v.resize( i-v.begin() );` that translates to a couple of arithmetic operations than leaving the container in a weird state.

Comment: @David: It might be my years of teaching showing through. I have learned the hard way that, when teaching something, you must never cut seemingly irrelevant corners, because students tend to pick up those cuts better than the relevant information. `:(` The key here, IMO, is that the STL operates on _sequences_, denoted by iterators, and for its most parts doesn't care whether the data is actually in a container somewhere, and whether that container holds more data than what you feed the algorithm. Code catering to that can be more elegant and faster than other code. And while we all agree...

Comment: ...that premature optimization is evil, if a different take on your approach can make things faster, then not exploring that is like not learning to pass `std::string` by `const` reference instead of by copy - or sticking to doing so even though move semantics might render it wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Read the documentation for `std::remove` again.

The function does not remove elements from a container (in fact, it doesn't even *know* that a container is involved, as it only sees iterators), it merely moves values in a sequence and return a new iterator `i` such that all the interval `[ begin .. i [`  contains all non-removed elements in the original order. Elements left over in `[ i .. end [` are unspecified, and it is your responsibility to eliminate that interval from a container (if you need it):

```
auto i = std::remove(...);
v.erase(i,v.end());
```

The reason why you have an additional `5` is that the typical removal algorithm *copies* values into holes left by removed values, and since values past the `i` iterator are never overwritten, they remain the same as in the original sequence. This behavior, however, is not reliable - just eliminate the values past `i` without reading them.

Answer (score 2):

`remove` returns the *new* end. So the fix of your code is this:

```
 std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
 auto newEnd = std::remove(v.begin(),v.end(),3);//return value stored in newEnd
 for(auto j = v.begin(); j!= newEnd ;++j) //note j!=newEnd
     std::cout << *j;
```

Output:

```
1245
```

Check it out yourself : http://www.ideone.com/3AMD9

Answer (score 2):

Actually, [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) moves at beginning of the range all elements which don't satisfy predicate, AND returns iterator of the new end.

So usage is [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 3), v.end());
```

In c++20, it can be simplified thanks to [`std::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2):

```
std::erase(v, 3);
```

Answer (score -3):

It's seams that you are printing the n+1 position of the vector in the `for()` statement.
It should be:

```
for(auto j = v.begin(); j!= v.end();j++)
   std::cout << *j;
```

`j++` no `++j`

Comment: In the context of a `for` loop, `j++` and `++j` are equivalent (though, for iterators, there may be performance differences).

Comment: in this context, `j++` and `++j` result in the same behavior.